# How to revert the printing of PowerPoint slides to A4 pages in PDF with 2 slides each?

Tags: pdf, printing, powerpoint, slideshow, presentation

I have a teacher who shows PowerPoint presentations in his classes but, when sending us the files, he does the "print to PDF" thing and, instead of uploading the slides themselves, he prints two slides per A4 page and uploads that. You can see an example in the following link:

https://leicmybox.org/LEIC/3%C2%BA%20Ano/1%C2%BA%20Semestre/RC/Te%C3%B3ricas/2016-2017/Teorica_8_2016_2017.pdf

This is very anoying, because there is no way to change between slides in a quick way when I need to compare the changes in an image, for example. I would like to know how to make these A4 pages back into slides.

I tried printing the A4 pages using settings from Adobe Acrobat Reader, such like changing the scale, but it does not work.

EDIT: Dividing A4 portrait pages into two A5 landscape won't work, because the resulting A5 pages won't have the same upper and bottom margins, so, even if I zoom in, there will still be blank space either over or bellow the image.

Comment: The thing is, if I divide A4 portrait to A5 landscape, the resulting A5 pages won't have the same upper and bottom margins, so, even if I zoom in, there will still be blank space either over or bellow the image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a solution, the following website does exactly what I needed:
https://online2pdf.com/en/cut-pdf-pages-into-halves
[image]